# Not able to install GWT Plugin as of May 2018 in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Please reply for both the issues.

**Issue 1:**
The installation of GWT Plugin through eclipse marketplace was working fine until last month. But now as I check there is some issue. The URL http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release is not reachable. This url is used to install the plugin in eclipse.

**Issue 2**
Also I tried compiling the source code from https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin. I am also pasting part of the log output for reference:

[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/mars
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20160221192158/repository
[INFO] Adding repository https://dl.google.com/eclipse/google-cloud-eclipse/stable
[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition C:\Work\softwares\gwt-eclipse-plugin-master\eclipse\mars\gwt-eclipse-mars.target: Could not find "com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.suite.feature.feature.group/1.6.0.201803071812" in the repositories of the current location -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.MavenExecutionException: Failed to resolve target definition C:\Work\softwares\gwt-eclipse-plugin-master\eclipse\mars\gwt-eclipse-mars.target: Could not find "com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.suite.feature.feature.group/1.6.0.201803071812" in the repositories of the current location
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:100)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:266)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared.BuildFailureException: Failed to resolve target definition C:\Work\softwares\gwt-eclipse-plugin-master\eclipse\mars\gwt-eclipse-mars.target: Could not find "com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.suite.feature.feature.group/1.6.0.201803071812" in the repositories of the current location
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContent(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolverService.resolveFromArguments(TargetDefinitionResolverService.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolverService.getTargetDefinitionContent(TargetDefinitionResolverService.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.resolveTargetDefinitions(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.manager.ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(P2DependencyResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.facade.TargetDefinitionResolutionException: Could not find "com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.suite.feature.feature.group/1.6.0.201803071812" in the repositories of the current location
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$LoadedIULocation.findUnitInThisLocation(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$LoadedIULocation.getRootIUs(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$ResolverRun.addLocation(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContentWithExceptions(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContent(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:94)
        ... 24 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException

Comment: I am using Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: We had a migration issue with the repo. It's back up and is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin

This is a fork of the old plugin, but is still maintained and has a bunch of extra features.

Look at the GitHub page for documentation (also in the form of videos).

Also available in Eclipse Marktplace:  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gwt-eclipse-plugin

Comment: I've had reports it's working. If it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: I tried the install today and it's working. I downloaded Eclipse Oxygen 3A and installed the plugin through the marketplace and it works.

Comment: Yes now it's working. Must be a temporary issue in googleapis.com

Comment: Doesn't seem to work today (February 2019) I get the error message "No repository found at http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release."